# Edit pdf with external application programatically

Tags: android, file, android-intent, kotlin, android-fileprovider

I have a request to make my application edit PDF files. Because I found it hard to integrate into the application, I decided to go with the external app and decided to use [Xodo reader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xodo.pdf.reader&hl=en_GB).

The problem I am having is that when my pdf is opened in the Xodo app and edited, it's not being saved to its original location, but rather a copy is saved to the Download folder. To me, this indicates that the app isn't able to save the edited file back to it's original destination, and I believe it's because I didn't do something right.

*Why do I think this?*

When Xodo app opens a .pdf file and then edits it when I hit back it saves it to the memory location it is opened from. When I load it with my app, it doesn't work that way.

Here is my code:

**How I call the application**

```
    val target = view?.packageManager?.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.xodo.pdf.reader")
    target?.action = Intent.ACTION_EDIT
    target?.setDataAndType(FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, view?.applicationContext?.packageName + ".fileprovider", report.file), "application/pdf")
    target?.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY
    target?.flags = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION

    view?.startActivity(target)
```

**What my @xml/provider_pathslooks like**

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <external-path name="myApp" path="."/>
</paths>
```

**Where my file is located in the memory**

> /Internal storage/myApp

**What my content URI looks like**

> content://com.example.myapp.debug.fileprovider/myApp/myApp/example0.pdf

Does anybody have a clue what I am doing wrong and where?

Answer (score 2):

Try granting both `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` and `FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION`. Right now, you are only granting read access, and so Xobo has no ability to write back to the provider.

Note that there is nothing that *requires* Xobo to write back to the provider, so even if you grant write access, Xobo may still write the modified PDF to a separate file.

Comment: I have tried that, but with that flag, the app doesn't open and displays error "Cannot open file"

Comment: @Pavle37: Did you grant both flags, or just write access?

Comment: @Pavle37: Then you'll have to ask Xobo.